# Can't get SQL Server Print message with PHP PDO

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, pdo

I'm using PDO (dblib driver) to call a SQL Server stored procedure. When it errors, it uses the PRINT  to generate a return message. The issue is that I can't get the message with errorInfo function. The result is empty and the rowcount also returns -1.

For example, When I run the stored procedure in sql server management studio:

```
CALL x_prodcedure 1,2
```

It outputs (not a rowset): `Invalid ID/data`

When I make the same call in php, no rowset data is found and errorinfo returns:

```
Array
(
  [0] => 00000
  [1] => 0
  [2] => (null) [0] (severity 0) [(null)]
  [3] => 0
  [4] => 0
)
```

Not sure which other functions I can use to get the "Invalid ID/data" message

Answer (score 0):

Actually `PDO ERROR 000` is the value of the error when a query executed successfully.

You should only print when it fails, otherwise you should ignore.

In your case something along the lines:

```
if(!$stmt->execute(array(...))){
   var_dump($dbh->errorInfo()); //not outside of the failure block
}else{
   var_dump($stmt->fetchAll());
}
```

Most likely `not a rowset` is  not considered as an error for `PDO`

Answer (score 0):

So far the best way I found to capture MS SQL Server messages in PHP was using the sybase extension built with ct library, freetds and using the sybase_set_message_handler() function. Example code:

```
<?
   $con = sybase_connect("server", "sa", "password");
   sybase_set_message_handler("dbMsg", $con);
   sybase_min_client_severity(0); // In case you want all messages
   sybase_min_server_severity(0); // In case you want all messages
   $rs = sybase_query("PRINT 'OK'; WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'; PRINT 'OK1';");
   $rs = sybase_query("USE SOMEDB; PRINT 'OK'; SE LECT 1"); // Intentionally with error

   function dbMsg($number, $severity, $state, $line, $text) {
      echo microtime(1) . " [{$number}] [{$severity}] [{$state}] [{$line}] [{$text}]\n";
   }
?>
```

Example build on a Debian Jessie:

```
cd /usr/src
apt-get source php5
cd [php source folder]/ext/sybase_ct
phpize
./configure --with-sybase-ct=/usr
make
make install
```

Note that this build procedure is not compatible with the mssql extension as the mssql one aliases the sybase functions.